# Python: keep only letters in string

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is the best way to remove all characters from a string that are not in the alphabet? I mean, remove all spaces, interpunction, brackets, numbers, mathematical operators..

For example:

```
input: 'as32{ vd"s k!+'
output: 'asvdsk'
```

Answer (score 67):

You could use `re`, but you don't really need to.

```
>>> s = 'as32{ vd"s k!+'
>>> ''.join(x for x in s if x.isalpha())
'asvdsk'    
>>> filter(str.isalpha, s) # works in python-2.7
'asvdsk'
>>> ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, s)) # works in python3
'asvdsk'
```

Answer (score 41):

If you want to use regular expression, this should be quicker:

```
import re
s = 'as32{ vd"s k!+'
print(re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]+', '', s))
```

prints `'asvdsk'`

Answer (score 4):

Here is a method that uses ASCII ranges to check whether an character is in the upper/lower case alphabet (and appends it to a string if it is):

```
s = 'as32{ vd"s k!+'
sfiltered = ''

for char in s:
    if((ord(char) >= 97 and ord(char) <= 122) or (ord(char) >= 65 and ord(char) <= 90)):
        sfiltered += char
```

The variable `sfiltered` will show the result, which is `'asvdsk'` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This simple expression get all letters, including non ASCII letters ok t áàãéèêçĉ... and many more used in several languages.

```
r"[^\W\d]+"
```

It means "get a sequence of one or more characters that are not either "non word characters" or a digit.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to preserve characters like áàãéèêçĉ that are used in many languages around thw world, try this:

```
import re
print re.sub('[\W\d_]+', '', yourString)
```

Comment: You're missing the argument to sub into the string:
`re.sub('[\W\d_]+', '', yourString)`