# A folder contains files of dog breeds like `Boston_terrier_02303.jpg`. I want to remove the numeric parts and also the `_`. How do I achieve this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My folder contains `.jpg` files in folder. I need to  fetch only the `characters` from the file names.

[I removed all the non alphabets but it resulted in a single string without spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34214139/python-keep-only-letters-in-string)

Input: `Boston_terrier_02303.jpg`
Desired Output: `Boston terrier`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you always have the same structure (n word fragments, 1 number, and the output), you can simply get your desired result by:

```
new_string = " ".join(string.split("_")[:-1])
```

To elaborate:
You start by splitting the strings at the underscores, and then selecting everything but the last. Then simply join the remaining strings with a space between them.

Comment: And filename extension?

Comment: since you are splitting at the underscores, the ".jpg" will also be part of the last element in the list; since we are dropping that, we are also dropping the ".jpg"

Comment: Yes, that's my point, but OP hasn't clearly formulated what he's trying to achieve.

Comment: why? He clearly specified the desired output, which consists of only the name of the dog breed.

Comment: @dennlinger thank you so much. That was just it. And the `[:-1]` removes doesn't include the last `_` and thus removes the part after it. Correct?

Comment: @bipll I just need the name of the dog breed without any extension and numbers. Thank you for your insight. :)

Comment: Yes. The `.split("_")` implicitly removes any `_` from your filenames anyways, so it's not included. And the `[:-1]` is basically a selector of "everything but the last element". Please consider accepting the answer if it should fit your desired result.

Comment: @dennlinger Sure. Thanks again. :)